# Selenium does not throw exception after timeout

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using selenium 2.53.1 in Java, I was expecting an exception if the required element was not found after some timeout. But actually, my test just waits for ever :-(

Here is my code. I first click on a button to perform some angular processes :

```
final WebDriver driver = Browser.getCurrentDriver();
final WebElement bouton = driver.findElement(By.id("bouton-id"));
bouton.click();
```

Then I wait at most 30 seconds for the element :

```
final WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("element-id")));
System.out.println(element);
```

Here, if the element did not appear before 30 seconds, doesn't it throw an exception?

Th.

Comment: yes, it should throw exception only after 30 seconds if it is not appear

Comment: why not try with Thread.sleep(30000) and then access the element with id.

Comment: at which point your code is stuck ?? are you sure it's not stuck at `bouton.click();`

Comment: @Kapil Because `Thread.sleep()` is a bad practice and should be avoided.

Comment: If I were to guess, you are probably using implicit waits? You shouldn't mix implicit and explicit waits per the docs for this specific reason.

Comment: Have you tried this?  I use this for waiting.  ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()

Comment: Actually Gaurang has a good point. Angular should perform things when the button is clicked, but it does not on jenkins. It actually does on my computer... Anyway, the timeout should work, no?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the exception handle concept using try catch block